# Why was this question about the Windows Phone 8 emulator closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Pretty simple question: [Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/windows-phone-8-emulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet-hyper-v-connection-setti)

I don't understand at all why it was closed in the first place as off-topic. It clearly covers "programing tools". It's not the best written question, but I think it's constructive.

For reference, I came across this question because I have this exact same problem and had rather not ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Probably a better fit for Super&nbsp;User rather than Stack&nbsp;Overflow if it actually is a config issue.

Comment: While the emulator is programming related, one might argue that the OP is dealing with an internet connection issue for his software which is not all that programming related. Super User material perhaps. I am not entirely sure I find it on-topic...

Comment: @Bart well, it's also Hyper-V related, making it a fit for SuperUser, but it's definitely not plain vanilla Hyper-V and no one but programmers will be using the Windows Phone 8 emulato

Comment: Yeah, I would not have actively closed it. I can see the confusion though.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't have been closed, but apparently opinions differ.  You encounter this in the closed-votes review queue -- if a programming question scarcely mentions a server or network issue, someone is going to want to close it as off topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some people aren't comfortable with the idea of having questions that don't entail any sort of (apparent) programming workflow, even if they're about programming tools, on Stack Overflow. See [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b).

I don't know about the duplicate links, but it certainly isn't off topic (and I'm not even a Windows Phone developer... although that $8 promotion looks tempting as hell). I've reopened it.

Comment: The whole formulation doesn't help a lot either. It takes a bit of a read to discover that it's a programming-related issue after the dual-boot install, internet connection, proxies and firewalls.

Comment: @Bart: You have a point there.

Comment: @Bart I cleaned up the question a bit and removed some irrelevant parts. also, if you think it would be a better fit at SuperUser then vote to close that way. All I really want is an answer :)

Comment: you might need to re-open it again soon - as of now it collected yet another four brainless off-topic votes. **[The current review system encourages fake reviews...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621/165773)**

Comment: @gnat: Yup, I've had a tab open for it all night long.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn tab open I see - good idea. I favourited but was worried that it'll somehow slip through still. I opened tab too - thanks for the hint...

Comment: @gnat If BoltClock overrides a community closure again I'll be asking for his diamond to be removed. Typical teen mod attitude.

Comment: @YannisRizos no, if that happens, let's remove diamond of casperOne, he's the only one to blame for stuff like that. :) On a more serious note, I think in this case one would better use term "mob" not "community"

Comment: @gnat Argh, you didn't fell for it... ;P

Answer (score 4):

Programming tools are on topic when doing programming things with the tool. But this isn't so much about using the tool as it is an internet connection question. That *can* be on topic for StackOverflow if you stretch it, but it's really a *better* fit for Superuser, and *Superuser has an audience that's more likely to be able to give you a good answer*. What flags this as off for me is the fact that the programming part is entirely irrelevant to the question. Remove the fact that you're trying to get some programming done and you still have exactly the same question.